# A function that turns a power to a product/sum?

Tags: calculus, functions, logarithms, linearization

I just recently started learning about the logarithm functions, and its concept is quite amazing (f(x.y)=f(x)+f(y)).
Now I'm asking for a similar function but instead of x.y ; we use `x^(y)` (like f(`x^(y)`)=f(x).f(y)/or a sum.... or it could involve another function whatsoever).
Something like (Linearization?) but in calculus (Sorry my vocab isn't that great).
Thank you

Comment: That is  a good question.  The answer there are only "trivial" such functions, because exponentiation is not associative.  That is to say  $a^{(b^c)} \ne (a^b)^c$.  So we'd need $f((x^y)^z) = f(x^y)*f(z) = f(x)f(y)f(z) = f(x)f(y^z) = f(x^{(y^z)})$  That only happens with $f(x) =1$ or $f(x) = 0$ of $f(0) = 0; f(x\ne 0) = 1$ or such uninteresting functions.

Comment: Also because it's not commutative: you'd need $f(x^y) = f(y^x)$.  Take $y=1$ and you get $f(x)=f(1)$.

Comment: On the other hand, the logarithm does turn a power to a product, in the sense $\log(x^y) =  \log(x) \cdot y$.